# Can I do a setup like Azure HdInsight on Azure virtual machine?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-hdinsight, azure-virtual-network

I would like to have a setup like Azure HDInsight on Azure VM and where I have to install and configure Hadoop to maintain the entire Hadoop and spark ecosystem, and most important thing is, I can only pay for a virtual machine, not for the software I have installed and I should achieve the same performance an HDInsight is that possible.

Answer (score 1):

As HDinsight is based on Hortonworks HDP, you might be able to get to a fairly similar system by installing something like the HDP sandbox on a VM: https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/hortonworks-sandbox.html

Generally: You can of course always just provision VM(s) and install an entire Hadoop distribution of your choice in there which gives you the full freedom to do and configure anything you like in there. If you get to the same performance as HDinsight depends then largely on your ability to properly configure and scale an Hadoop cluster.

Comment: If I have a setup like that, is that same as visualizing the data from the Azure SQL database to PowerBI with data from SQL Server in Azure VM to power BI. I mean is that again same as a cloud to cloud or the performance may vary. Can I proceed it as a solution for my client.

Comment: I don't quite understand your comparison to SQL and PowerBi. But performance-wise in terms of network latency: Yes this setup would be the same as with HDinsight. HDinsight also uses plain VMs under the hood.

Comment: I'm not comparing, is the speed of accessing the data from SQL database in Azure VM with power bi service is same as accessing the data from Azure SQL database to power bi service

Comment: So this question is not related to your HDinsight question?! Network latency should still be pretty much the same. In terms of read performance this depends on how beefy your VM is vs. how big you scaled your Azure SQL Database

Answer (score 0):

Can I do a setup like Azure HDInsight on Azure Virtual Machine?

Yes, you can setup like Azure HDInsight on Azure Virtual Machine.

**Note:** **Azure HDInsight is built on top of Hortonworks Data platform**.

You have four different options to deploy Hadoop.

**1. Azure HDInsights (Built on top of HDP)**

[**Azure HDInsight**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/hdinsight/) is a managed, full-spectrum, open-source analytics service for enterprises. HDInsight is a cloud service that makes it easy, fast, and cost-effective to process massive amounts of data. HDInsight also supports a broad range of scenarios, like extract, transform, and load (ETL); data warehousing; machine learning; and IoT.

**2. HDP as a Service in Azure Marketplace**

The Azure cloud infrastructure has become a common place for users to deploy virtual machines on the cloud due to its flexibility, ease of deployment, and cost benefits. Microsoft has expanded Azure to include a marketplace with thousands of certified, open source, and community software applications and developer services, pre-configured for Microsoft Azure. This tutorial covers deploying the Hortonworks Sandbox offering via the Azure Marketplace.

For a step-by-step guide on how to deploy the Hortonworks Sandbox on Azure, visit: [Deploying Hortonworks Sandbox on Microsoft Azure](https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/sandbox-deployment-and-install-guide/section/4/#create-hortonworks-data-platform-sandbox-in-azure).

**3. Deploying HDP on bare metal**

The sandbox provides a local development environment to learn about Hadoop, Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS), and job submission.

For a step-by-step guide on [Get started with an Apache Hadoop Sandbox, an emulator on a Virtual Machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/apache-hadoop-emulator-get-started#set-sandbox-passwords).

**4. Create a Linux VM and install Hadoop eco-system manually**.

You can setup Hadoop eco-system on Azure Virtual Machine running linux.
For a step-by-step guide on how to install Hadoop on Azure VM.

- [Introduction](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/oliviaklose/2014/06/17/hadoop-on-linux-on-azure-1/)
- [Step-by-Step: Build the Infrastructure](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/oliviaklose/2014/06/18/hadoop-on-linux-on-azure-step-by-step-build-the-infrastructure-2/)
- [Step-by-Step: Install a Hadoop Distribution](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/oliviaklose/2014/07/02/hadoop-on-linux-on-azure-step-by-step-install-hadoop-3/)

Hope this helps.